# General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have very weird problem while trying to create new item. Code and error below.

Mugration:

```
Schema::create('inventory_departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default('1');
            //$table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('inventory_departments');
        });
```

Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
            'title',
            'parent_id',
        ];
```

Controller:

```
$data = [
        'title' => 'test',
        'parent_id' => '3',
    ];

    $result = InventoryDepartment::create($data);
```

And i receive such error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `inventory_departments` () values ())
```

Comment: There are no error on your above code

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be passing in `$data` to create?

```
$result = InventoryDepartment::create($data);
```

Comment: Does the issue persist?

Comment: Yes, using tranfered data, or using this data, result the same.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Model and Controller